# Adjusting methods within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, methods

I am having issues with properly implementing the following:

> Remove `__hours` and `__minutes`. 
>   Adjust the implementation of the mutator and accessor methods. For
>   example, for `__init__(hr, min, sec)`, validate the values, then set
>   `__seconds = hr * 60 * 60 + min * 60 + sec`. This will store the time as seconds. Adjust all the methods to work with `__seconds`. `getSecond()`
>   can use `__seconds` mod 60 to return only the seconds in the time. Test
>   all the methods to make sure they still work. (mod is modulus, the
>   remainder after a division.)

I have used this in my code `self.setSecond = (hour * 60 * 60) + (minute * 60 + second)`

To properly represent hour, minute and seconds to just seconds I am however having issues with implementing the rest of the program. I'm not sure if I should be printing out just seconds? Also when I change my getSecond() function to return `% 60` it is not doing so. I'm assuming because I'm not properly calling it?

Here is my code thus far:

```
class Clock(object):

    def __init__(self, hour, minute, second):
        self.setHour(hour)
        self.setMinute(minute)
        self.setSecond = (hour * 60 * 60) + (minute * 60 + second)

    def setHour(self, hour):
        self.__hour = hour
        if self.__hour > 23:
            self.__hour = 0
        elif self.__hour < 0:
            self.__hour = 0

    def getHour(self):
        return self.__hour

    def setMinute(self, minute):
        self.__minute = minute
        if self.__minute > 60:
            self.__minute = 0
        elif self.__minute < 0:
            self.__minute = 0

    def getMinute(self):
        return self.__minute

    def setSecond(self, second):
        self.__second = second
        if self.__second > 60:
            self.__second = 0
        elif self.__second < 0:
            self.__second = 0

    def getSecond(self):
        return self.__second

    def __str__(self):
        if self.__hour > 11:
            return 'The Time is {}:{}:{} PM'.format(self.__hour, self.__minute, self.__second)
        else:
            return 'The Time is {}:{}:{} AM'.format(self.__hour, self.__minute, self.setSecond)


stopwatch = Clock(3, 2, 1)
print(stopwatch)
```

Note: I am aware that this code isn't very pythonic but that is how I was told to keep it (I apologize).

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 changes required primarily:

1. You don't need to maintain hours and minutes in the class. You maintain only the seconds. So remove the `setHour` and `setMinute` methods.
2. Because you don't maintain the hours and minutes, the `getHour` and `getMinute` methods should do the required calculation.

   ```
   def getHour(self):
       return int(self.__second / 3600)

   def getMinute(self):
       return int(self.__second / 60) % 60
   ```
3. In the `init` function, call to self.setSecond is not correct. It should be:

   ```
   def __init__(self, hour, minute, second):
       if hour > 23 or hour < 0:
           hour = 0
       if minute > 60 or minute < 0:
           minute = 0
       if second > 60 or second < 0:
           second = 0
       self.setSecond((hour * 60 * 60) + (minute * 60 + second))
   ```
4. And although you mentioned, your `getSecond()` method does not do a `seconds % 60`. It should be:

   ```
   def getSecond(self):
       return self.__second % 60
   ```
5. In method `def __str__`, instead of directly accessing the hours, minutes, seconds, use the accessor methods:

   ```
   def __str__(self):
       if self.getHour() > 11:
           return 'The Time is {}:{}:{} PM'.format(self.getHour(), self.getMinute(), self.getSecond())
       else:
           return 'The Time is {}:{}:{} AM'.format(self.getHour(), self.getMinute(), self.getSecond())
   ```
6. The `setSeconds` method should not have the check for `> 60` because now you will be storing a large number here:

   ```
   def setSecond(self, second):
       self.__second = second
       if self.__second < 0:
           self.__second = 0
   ```

Comment: So I implemented your code, however when printing out this clock for example:

clock1 = Clock(34, -100, 4345)
print(clock1)

It returns The Time is 33:32:25 PM. When all the variables should be resetting to 0s.

Comment: I have added the validation checks to `__init__`. Should work now.